# Crear rutas para servidor node y Express

Tags: nodejs, express, rutas

estoy creando un servidor con node, que es el siguiente:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/',function(request,res){
    res.sendfile('/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('El servidor Esta En llamas!');
});
```

El archivo se llama server.js y esta en la carpeta Desafio en conjunto al index.html. Dentro de la misma carpeta tengo la carpeta /css, /js, /img y etc...

la cosa es que necesito importar estas mismas desde su ubicación para que pueda tener todo corriendo....

Como correpsonde enruta las carpetas en node y on express?

saludos...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo, primero que todo, corrige tu código de manera que te quede así:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Para llamar los archivos css y js públicos desde tu index.html debes
// declarar las rutas como estáticas de la siguiente forma
app.use('/public/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/public/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/public/img', express.static(__dirname + '/img'));

app.get('/',function(request,res){
    // el método es sendFile (con F mayúscula) y debes agregar
    // la variable de entorno llamada __dirname que te da la ruta de 
    // de la raíz en tu actual proyecto
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('El servidor Esta En llamas!');
});
```

Luego en tu `index.html` puedes acceder a tus carpetas `css`, `js` e `img` de la siguiente forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/mi_archivo_css.css">
    <script src="./public/js/mi_archivo_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="./public/img/mi_imagen.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pero... por qué apareció "public" en esta configuración? Faltaría añadir que él debe crear un directorio "public" donde poner los assets estáticos

Comment: oh, ya entendí. Montaste todos los estáticos de la raíz del proyecto en una ruta public que en realidad no es un directorio físico

Comment: @amenadiel No es necesario, simplemente express hace un middleware para enrutar las peticiones de public a donde se enlazan en la configuración

Comment: @amenadiel exactamente

Comment: Gracias  a todos, tengo una duda y me confunde lo que es __dirname

Comment: Te dejo este [enlace](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) de la documentación oficial de nodejs (en inglés) acerca de que es `__dirname`